# Not replace if the text before is equal to

Tags: javascript, regex

The following is my replacement code:

`.replace(/java(script)/g,'$1')`

So `"some javascript to replace"` will become `"some script to replace"` after replacement. What I want is if the `javascript` starts with  `#`, I don't want to replace `#javascript` with `#script`. So the result of

`"some #javascript to replace"` should be `"some #javascript to replace"`

What regex should I use?

Comment: `.replace(/[^#]java(script)/g,'$1')`

Comment: @Mako That doesn't work as expected as it now removes the space between `some` and `javascript`, resulting in `somescript to replace` instead of `some script to replace`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following regex replacement:

```js
var s = "some javascript #javascript to replace";
s = s.replace(/(^|[^#])java(script)/g,'$1$2');
console.log(s);
```

**Details**:

- `(^|[^#])` - capturing group 1 matching either the start of string or any char other than `#`
- `java` - a literal char sequence `java`
- `(script)` - capturing group 2 matching a literal char sequence `script`.

In the replacement pattern, the captured parts are re-inserted into the resulting string, effectively removing `java` only if not preceded with `#` and followed with `script`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the character just before it using a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html), although you can use [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of capturing the `script` part. If necessary use [word boundary(`\b`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to avoid matching anything within a word.

```
.replace(/([^#]|^)\bjava(?=script\b)/g,'$1')
```

```js
console.log(
  "some #javascript to replace ajavascript javascript".replace(/([^#]|^)\bjava(?=script\b)/g, '$1')
)
```